# MS SQL sql statement returns empty result

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two tables:

### |idperson|workload|active|idpm|firstname|lastname|

### |idsupportday|date|fk_person|

and this SQL statement:

```
SELECT person.idperson, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.workload,
       person.active, person.idpm, COUNT(supportday.idsupportday) AS SupportDays,
       MIN(supportday.date) AS FirstDate, MAX(supportday.date) AS LastDate
FROM   person
INNER JOIN supportday 
ON         person.idperson = supportday.fk_person
WHERE      (person.active = 1)
GROUP BY   person.idperson, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.workload,
           person.active, person.idpm
```

Now if the `supportday` table is empty, I also receive an empty result. But I still want all persons with `person.active=1` in the result.

What do I need to change?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT person.idperson, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.workload,
       person.active, person.idpm, COUNT(supportday.idsupportday) AS SupportDays,
       MIN(supportday.date) AS FirstDate, MAX(supportday.date) AS LastDate
FROM   person
LEFT OUTER JOIN supportday 
ON         person.idperson = supportday.fk_person
WHERE      (person.active = 1)
GROUP BY   person.idperson, person.firstname, person.lastname, person.workload,
           person.active, person.idpm
```

- [MSDN: Using Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- [Writing Outer Joins in T-SQL](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/writing-outer-joins-in-t-sql)

> Inner joins return rows only when there is at least one row from both
>   tables that matches the join condition. Inner joins eliminate the rows
>   that do not match with a row from the other table. **Outer joins,
>   however, return all rows from at least one of the tables or views
>   mentioned in the FROM clause, as long as those rows meet any WHERE or
>   HAVING search conditions. All rows are retrieved from the left table
>   referenced with a left outer join**, and all rows from the right table
>   referenced in a right outer join.

Comment: Note: avoid `count(*)` (what is not the case here) in an outer join since you would count the rows returned(even if there would be no `SupportDay`). To prevent this you should explicitely specify the field (`COUNT(supportday.idsupportday)`), that'll eliminate `null` values from the count.

Answer (score 3):

Change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`